Help with understanding the frequency response of a simple error amplifier
I am trying to obtain the frequency response of an error amplifier I designed the circuit of which is shown on the left and the obtained frequency response in Simplis can be seen on the right.

I am using a VCCS with a gain of 2 mS and a current limit of 250 µA. I am driving this with a 1 mV ac signal to prevent driving the amplifier in to the non-linear region.
The expected response is a first order response with a gain of 57 dB and a pole at 5.6 kHz. However, I am obtaining a negative gain as seen in the response obtained.
Could anybody tell me what is going wrong here?
Thanks

Does V1 affect the result if 0?

Yes, I obtain the expected response when V1 is shorted. Could you comment on why that is the case?

Your bias V1,  should match the DC feedback which is zero.  Why is it open loop?

Isn't that true for an OPAMP or is it applicable for a VCCS as well?

true for both.  If there is high gain and a large DC input offset, the output will be limited at one extreme

Thanks! As you mentioned my dc operating points were wrong, hence the negative gain.

That is because you are only use 1mV for stimulus - that will drop the gain by 60dB.
For small signal simulation it is standard to use 1V stimulus. 1mV is 60dB lower than 1V so will give an output 60dB lower with a corresponding lower gain.
Don't worry about overload as the small signal simulation is not affected by large signal effects.

Could you elaborate on why a 1mV stimulus would drop the gain by 60dB?
